# Should these questions be moved here?

Tags: discussion

As they concern InDesign, should these two questions of mine regarding data import be moved here?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799322/how-would-i-import-this-data-into-indesign

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798093/repeating-item-templates-in-indesign-xml-import

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, seems a bit more superuser to me though, not design.

I suggest SuperUser because I think data merge issues will get better answers there. Few designers use data merge, but there are some who do. So yes, there could be answers here, but answers which are slower to appear and possibly not as thorough as they would be at SuperUser.

Absolutely not StackOverflow questions in my opinion.

Comment: When migrating questions, the idea is to think about where the question will get the best answers. It's not "where is this the most on-topic" because that can have a lot of overlap (think game dev vs stack overflow in a lot of cases); it's a question of which community will come up with the best answers. In this case I think you're right that SU is a good bet, but only if the SU mods want them.

Answer (score 0):

No, they shouldn't. They're not about graphic design itself, which is off-topic here. They're about the program, which would be more on-topic on SuperUser, as @Scott suggested. They may be on-topic on StackOverflow, because they both have something to do with XML, etc. The first question just has the wrong tags.